# PreferenceCategory class can not be found on pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, leanback

guys! I've met a problem. I'm using **support preference leanback** library to show settings.

In some cases I also need to show leanback settings on mobile devices, and on **pre Lollipop** devices the fragment **crashes** on inflation with this stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                  at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:280)
                  at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:35)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                  at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.getViewForPosition(GridLayoutManager.java:998)
                  at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager$3.createItem(GridLayoutManager.java:1485)
                  at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.SingleRow.appendVisibleItems(SingleRow.java:111)
                  at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Grid.appendOneColumnVisibleItems(Grid.java:364)
                  at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.appendOneColumnVisibleItems(GridLayoutManager.java:1721)
                  at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:1904)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
                at android.view.Vie
```

Noone knows, what goes after "at android.view.Vie", but I have localized the problem, and that is because mobile devices cannot find **PreferenceCategory** class/layout. If I remove PreferenceCategories from the preferences.xml file - everything works perfectly.

Support preference library was added too, but that **haven't resoved** the issue.

Do you have any ideas, why this can happen?

PS: If you need further information - I'll add more sources and answer all questions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is this for TV devices?

Comment: @NIPHIN this happens on all android devices with pre 5.0 OS version. But yes, preferences screen is for TV devices.

Comment: So, the problem was in the PreferenceCategory class. Somehow pre-Lollipop devices don't load it with class loader, and when parsing the preferences xml file - it fails with ClassNotFoundException (or similar), causing InflateException on a higher level.

My solution was to get rid of PreferenceCategory in the preferences.xml